# Implementing POP UP in Angular+Node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

Can anyone please suggest me How to implement a POP UP function in Angular + Node js?
I want to implement a login which should pop up when the user clicks login button.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what CSS framework you are using. I often use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), and the [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap) directives. This allows easy [modal dialog](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) display.

Comment: I am also using Bootstrap.Can you please help me with the POP UP implementation?

Comment: Here is a plunker that shows this implemented: http://plnkr.co/edit/gnHO5Q35q428Z1uARKiK?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the reply.If I create a partial html  How can I render it as a POP UP using angular route?

Comment: Hi.. You see the block: `<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">` - this is the template file override - remove this and then add this to the JS modal options: `templateUrl: 'my-modal.html'`.

Comment: Sorry - just re-read your comment - you asked about displaying a modal via a route.. try adding the call to `$modal..open()` to a controller method that is assigned to the route..

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Can you please give me an example.I am new to Angular. :( –

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79558/discussion-between-thefoot-and-user3062513).

Answer (score 0):

This is dummy html with bootstrap content that will trigger pop up on button click. You will notice I've placed `ng-click` directive on the login button, so you should just create angular function on your controller that is combined with this view.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modalExample">Login modal</button>

    <div class="modal fade modalExample" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModallable">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="username" placeholder="Username" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="login(username,password)">Login</button>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

This will handle your problem on the client side, and related to Node.js I suppose you will have some api controller that will listen for the request that you can send from angular factory that represents service.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways of doing this either with jQuery or angular.js.
ngDialog plugin is available you can go through it if you want popup with pure angular.